# String.compareTo method to compare

Tags: java, compareto

Will you check my Method and let me know what I'm doing wrong? thank you :)

```
public static void sortByVehicleMakeModel(Vehicle[] vehicles) {
    boolean swapped = true;

    for(int y = 0; y < vehicles.length && swapped; y++) {
        swapped=false;
        for(int x = 0; x < vehicles.length - (y+1); x++) {
            if(vehicles[x].getMake() && vehicles[x].getModel().compareTo(vehicles[x + 1].getMake() && vehicles[x].getModel())) {    
                swap(vehicles, x, x + 1);
                swapped=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my error is on the second statement .compareto()
The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String

However, this code works just fine:

```
public static void sortByOwnerName(Vehicle[] vehicles) {
    boolean swapped = true;

    for(int y = 0; y < vehicles.length && swapped; y++) {
        swapped=false;
        for(int x = 0; x < vehicles.length - (y + 1); x++) {
            if(vehicles[x].getOwner().getName().compareTo(vehicles[x + 1].getOwner().getName())> 0) {   
                swap(vehicles, x, x + 1);
                swapped=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The method is called sortByVehicleCost, but you are comparing with getMake() & getModel(). Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If you're just looking for constructive criticism, you might want to try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . If it's not working the way you expect or you don't understand the way it's working then elaborate on what you're getting, what is un-expected, what you're expecting etc.

Comment: Do make and model contribute to your vehicle cost?

Comment: Write your Vehicle class

Comment: What does getMake() and getModel() return? Int, String, objects, etc?

Comment: @Bhavik Ambani I have that! :(

Comment: @Niloo What are you saying ? What  you have that? YOu have not placed any code of `Vehicle` class.

Comment: @threenplusone    sortByVehicleMakeModel
i. Refer to the sortArrayAscending method from Lab6
ii. Get the cost of vehicle “x” and vehicle “x + 1”
1. Call the vehicle’s GetCost() method to get each vehicle’s cost
iii. Use the String.compareTo method to compare the vehicle’s cost values
iv. If necessary, call the swap method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding a `int getCost()` to the Vehicle object and then using something like `vehicles[x].getCost() > vehicles[x - 1].getCost()` for your if statement.

Also, this sort is not very efficient. Maybe Vehicle should implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and use `Collections.sort()` to sort.

---

Just read the update to your question.

Try this:

```
if (vehicles[x].getMake().compareTo(vehicles[x - 1].getMake()) < 0 || 
   (vehicles[x].getMake().compareTo(vehicles[x - 1].getMake()) == 0 &&
    vehicles[x].getModel().compareTo(vehicles[x - 1].getModel()) < 0)) {
```

Comment: I don't know about that, but it's required by my professor :(

Comment: I knew it has to be something like this, but I couldn't figure it out! :D you are awesome ;) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Both of the operands to the `&&` must be a `boolean` expression (either `true` or `false`):

In the follow either one of them or both of them are `String`.

```
vehicles[x].getMake() && vehicles[x].getModel().compareTo(vehicles[x + 1].getMake() && vehicles[x].getModel())
```

---

Rather than trying to sort the `Vehicle` objects with that logic, you should make a comparator for your `Vehicle`

```
public class VehicleComparator implements Comparator<Vehicle> {
    //...
    public int compare(Vehicle v1, Vehicle v2) {
       //..
    }
}
```

And use use the [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5b%5d,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method.

```
Arrays.sort(vehicles, new VehicleComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

For implementing the `compareTo()` method you must have to implement `Comparable<Type>` interface and override

```
public int compareTo(T o);
```

method which will return so instead of

```
vehicles[x].getModel().compareTo(vehicles[x + 1....
```

you should place

```
vehicles[x].getModel().compareTo(vehicles[x + 1.... > -1 // or any constant which you want to say as invalid.
```

Then only work

Hope this will help you.

Comment: No, the error is the same ( The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, )